# Optional deconstruction function parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

How do you modify the function below to make the second parameter optional?

**TypeScript:**

```
function getName(name: string, {
    lastName
  }: {
    lastName: string
  }) {
  // ...
}

getName('John'); // error
```

**Update:**

The solution I've found so far is to take out the deconstruction into the function body:

```
function getName(name: string, options: {
    lastName: string
  } = {} as any) {
    const { lastName } = options;
    // ...
}

getName('John'); // OK
```

However, I still cannot find how to make it work in this context:

```
const getName = Bluebird.coroutine(function* co(name: string,
  {
    lastName
  }: {
    lastName: string
  }) {
    // ...
});

getName('John'); // error


/* -------- DECLARATIONS -------- */

declare namespace Bluebird {
    interface CoroutineOptions {
        yieldHandler(value: any): any;
    }
}

declare class Bluebird<R> {
    static coroutine<T, A1, A2>(
        generatorFunction: (a1: A1, a2: A2) => IterableIterator<any>,
        options?: Bluebird.CoroutineOptions
    ): (a1: A1, a2: A2) => Bluebird<T>;
}
```

Moving the deconstruction to the function body still gives an error:

```
const getName = Bluebird.coroutine(function* co(name: string, options: {
    lastName: string
  } = {} as any) {
    // ...
});

getName('John'); // error: Expected 2 arguments but got 1.
```

Comment: Looking at the update, is the syntax correct? I'm not aware of a `function*` or the `coroutine`  as it is used in the example. Could this be clearly displayed?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to define the interface for the `lastName` property as optional when defining the options object. If no `options` is defined, the default object is an empty object {}.

```
function foo(required: string, options: { lastName?: string } = {}) {
    console.log(required);
    if (options.lastName) {
        console.log(options.lastName);
    }
}

foo('foo1')
foo('foo2', {})
foo('foo3', {lastName: 'bar'})
```

Running the above, the console output is:

```
foo1
foo2
foo3
bar
```

See [TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20foo(required%3A%20string%2C%20options%3A%20%7B%20lastName%3F%3A%20string%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(required)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(options.lastName)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(options.lastName)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo('foo1')%0D%0Afoo('foo2'%2C%20%7B%7D)%0D%0Afoo('foo3'%2C%20%7BlastName%3A%20'bar'%7D)) to try it out yourself.

Comment: Taking out the deconstruction works as I updated in the question. There is still a case that I can't figure when using Bluebird coroutines. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 2):

`options = {}` should work?

`function getName(name: string, options = {}) {}`