# Optional parameter object with deconstruction

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do I make the second parameter optional and use deconstruction?

So far this works, but it's a bit ugly. Anything better?

```
const fn = (required, optional = {id: undefined, name: undefined}) => {
  const {id, name} = optional
  console.log(required, id, name)
}

fn('hello') // hello undefined undefined
fn('hello', {id: 'world'}) // hello world undefined
fn('hello', {name: 'world'}) // hello undefined world
```

I found this for typescript, [Optional deconstruction function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684538/optional-deconstruction-function-parameter) , but I don't think I can apply the solution without TS.

Comment: `const fn = (required, {id = undefined, name = undefined}) => {`

Comment: ^Doesn't work. Errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same approach as the typescript solution you found works in ES6 as well:

```
function fn(required, {id, name} = {}) {
  console.log(required, id, name)
}
```

Use the destructuring expression as the target for the defaulted parameter, not `optional`. Also I've dropped the explicit property initialisation with `undefined`, just using an empty object as the default value works fine.

Comment: Thanks for coming to my rescue again Bergi!